# How to edit css of child component imported from other module Angular 2+

Tags: css, angular, sass

I use agm-snazzy-window from [amg-snazzy-window](https://github.com/atmist/snazzy-info-window#html-structure)

There is explanation that I can override css class but when I do it it won't work.
This is my example:

map-component.html

```
   <agm-snazzy-info-window [closeWhenOthersOpen]="true">
         <ng-template>
            My snazzy window
         </ng-template>
   </agm-snazzy-info-window>
```

I want to have wider content so I made this:
map-component.scss:

```
.si-content {
  width: 500px !important;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you need to use `::ng-deep`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
::ng-deep .si-content {
  width: 500px !important;
}
```

This will tell angular to attach correct `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated` classes to your styles. It doesn't do this by default because it cannot find them in your template.

Without `::ng-deep`, your style will be `.si-content[_ngcontent-1]`, or something similar. In such case `[_ngcontent-1]` comes from the `map-component`. Using `::ng-deep` you instruct angular to look for "deeper" to find correct component `agm-snazzy-info-window`.

Comment: So by default it should be just `.si-content` but for now it can not find some class or module?

Comment: I updated the answer, hope it helps. It's best to inspect code in dev tools with and without `::ng-deep` to see the difference and what's going on...

Comment: It has been deprecated and support is being removed from major browsers and tools. As such, support in Angular (for all 3 of /deep/, >>> and ::ng-deep) will be dropped. Until then ::ng-deep should be preferred for a broader compatibility with the tools. https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep