# Angular GoogleMaps Marker InfoWindow scrollbar not getting hidden

Tags: css, angular

I'm trying to customise the popup info window that appears when you click on a marker, but I can't get rid of the scrollbar that appears on the right in case the content overflows.

https://pasteboard.co/Ith8X2v.png (image was not loading when used the image template)

I've tried adding `overflow: scroll` too all the parent containers as it seems that's the only thing the was different (see [this](https://jsfiddle.net/qpLxrvwy/)).

I've made a little clip with what kinda worked but not entirely.
https://streamable.com/guoei

Markers code:

```html
  <agm-marker *ngFor="let m of markers; let i = index"
              (markerClick)="clickedMarker(m.label, i)"
              [latitude]="m.lat"
              [longitude]="m.lng"
              [label]="m.label"
              [markerDraggable]="m.draggable">

    <agm-info-window>
      <div class="popup-info-container">
          <div class="popup-header-container">
              <strong>InfoWindow content</strong>
          </div>
          <div class="popup-body-container">
              <strong>InfoWindow content</strong>
          </div>
      </div>
    </agm-info-window>

  </agm-marker>
```

CSS code:

```css
.popup-info-container {
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  &::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
  } 
}

.agm-info-window-content {
  overflow: scroll;
}

.popup-header-container {
  height: 20%;
  width: 95%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.popup-body-container {
  height: 75%;
  width: 95%;
  background-color:whitesmoke;
}
```

I want to get something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/qpLxrvwy/):
where the scrollbar fadesout.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a similar thing here [How to edit css of child component imported from other module Angular 2+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48589968/how-to-edit-css-of-child-component-imported-from-other-module-angular-2)

Basically I had to override classes that angular was generating with `::ng-deep`

```
::ng-deep .gm-style {
  .gm-style-iw-d::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```